# Can't get drive hub out of washing machine to replace gearcase

Tags: washing-machine, stuck

I have a Kenmore "VMW" model 110.21302012

I am pretty certain the problem with this machine is the gearcase has worn out. To that end, I already have purchased and received the replacement, as well as a replacement drive hub and belt.

I am now stuck. Or, I should say, the drive hub is stuck -- I can't free the old gearcase from the washer. It is as if the multiple pieces of the drive hub, and the gear shaft, have fused together into a single piece.

I bought some Supco "Rust Buster" penetrating oil. Was advised in a repair video that that would help.

Does anyone have any advice on freeing these parts?

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my own question.

I resolved this by

- whacking the heck out of the drive hub with a hammer
- using "rust buster" penetrating oil in all the cracks
- eventually, i had to drill out one of the stuck screws
- then finally, I split the center piece in half with a metal chisel

Summary: Brute force removal method. Good thing I had already bought a replacement hub assembly.